# Chef: Insufficient permissions creating a directory in C:

Tags: ruby, windows, chef-infra

I'm experiencing an error while trying to create a directory in C:\Program Files using Chef. I am running chef from a powershell environment as Administrator, so there shouldn't be any restrictions as to what actions I can perform.

**recipes/default.rb**

```
directory node['app']['unzip_path'] do
  action :create
end
```

**attributes/default.rb**

`default['app']['unzip_path'] = 'C:/Program files/App'`

I'm getting this error:

```
[2013-06-25T01:51:13+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::InsufficientPermissions: directory[C:/Program files/App] (app::agent line 15) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::InsufficientPermissions: Cannot create directory[C:/Program files/App] at C:/Program files/App due to insufficient permissions
```

Additional question: Does chef-solo run as the user running the powershell command or is it running as a special "chef" user

Comment: Regular users can't write there.

Comment: Edited my post to reflect that Chef is being run as administrator

Answer (score 3):

Following up on BrianJakovich's answer.
The `mkdir_p` call should preserve idempotence in either case, but using a ruby block will probably be better since it will run at the convergence phase:

```
ruby_block "hack to mkdir on windows" do
    block do
        FileUtils.mkdir_p node['app']['unzip_path']
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3787?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel](http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3787?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) it looks like this is a bug. My resolution to this is to just go the ruby route

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.mkdir_p node['app']['unzip_path']
```

The problem here is that I lose the idempotence property that chef's directory resource provides, but if you need to put stuff into program files, this seems to be the only route for now

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this kind of issue with chef not allowing you to make changes inside C:\Program Files\
is to create a simple batch script file like:

```
@ECHO OFF
MKDIR "C:\\Program Files\\YourDirectory"
:END
```

And name it programfiles_yourdirectory.bat.erb, then
Add it under templates on your cookbook and on the recipe call it like:

```
template "C:\\chef\\cache\\programfiles_yourdirectory.bat" do
  source "programfiles_yourdirectory.bat.erb"
  rights :full_control, "Administrators"
end

execute "Create Program Files_YourDirectory Directory" do
  cwd "C:\\chef\\cache"
  command "programfiles_yourdirectory.bat"
  action :run
  not_if do ::File.exists?('C:\Program Files\YourDirectory') end
end
```

This will create a bat template inside chef\cache folder, then chef-client will run the bat file with Admin rights meaning that the folder will be created without prompting for chef insufficient permissions.